# Can't center the logo

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to center my logo it is in a div with the id "logocont" here is my css code no matter how i tried is stay stuck at the left if i put display block my navigation bar goes in another line and logo will be centered.

```
#logocont {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin : 0 auto;
    overflow : visible;
}
```

Note: I am using grid layout I created the grids in another css file and i am linking it.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="gr-16" id="menu">
    <div id="logocont" class="gr-2">
        <a href="#">
            <img id="logo" src="images/mylogo21.png" alt="Logo" runat="server" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="gr-5">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">
                Home
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                Programmers
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                Request Program
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? For example: HTML code of #logocont, other css styles which might affect the div or the logo... Also a working sample of the div with a example image in jsfiddle could let us help you better.

Comment: Have you also tried `align-self: center;`?

Comment: I added HTML code and no I haven't yet tried this code let me try it.

Comment: Normally you assign the [margin : 0 auto;] to the element you want to center, not to the container. And [text-align: center] is used for the containers. It would help to see the css related to the Logo also, not only the container.

Comment: the div is holding only the logo and it take its size so if I centered its div element it will automatically be centered. the logo has no css yet.

Comment: thanks alot I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing the nav tag from the div as well as the logo so my code became:

```
<div class="gr-16" id="menu">
    <nav id="navbar">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Programers</a>
        <a href="#">Request Program</a>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" id="logocont">
        <img id="logo" src="images/mylogo21.png" alt="Logo" runat="server" />
    </a>
</div>
```

and changed the css to:

```
#logocont {
    width : 100px;
    display : block;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use display inline-flex for your logo container

```
#logocont {
 display: inline-flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It's important to note Flexbox's [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) before recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

This example centers a div in a div:

```
<html>
<style>
    #outer {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #inner {
        display: inline-block;
        }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">Foo foo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following CSS to make a vertically and horizontally aligned div accordingly to what i understood from your HTML. May you check if this helps? (link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/est02o5m/1/)

CSS:

```
.gr-16 {
  display: grid;
}

.gr-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
}

.gr-5 {
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-column-end: 8;
}

#logocont {
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-flex;
    float: none;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin : 0 auto;
    overflow : visible;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: #ccc;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

If the css that i used doesn't correspond to what you're using may you complement it and update your question?